# How to cache network videos in flutter application?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, video-player

Im trying to understand what caching videos means and how exactly it works.

The problem that I had was a high bandwidth in my flutter /firebase application . I had like 19gb a day with 10-20 videos and like up to 10 users. So I could not figure out what the problem was. Therefore I contacted firebase support and they say

```
Looking at the graph, the high bandwidth comes from the storage bucket where the videos are stored. Even though it looks like there are few videos, your bandwidth will increase more and more if your application doesn't store the videos in cache.

Try to double check your applications and ensure that these ones download the information only once.
```

And I was like what the hak is chaching? And how to do it ?
And will this solve the problem of high bandwidth?

here's how my code looks like

```
class Videoplayeritem extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool mute;
  final int pickedvideo;

  final int currentPageIndex;
  final bool isPaused;
  final int pageIndex;
  final String videourl;
  final String thumbnailUrl;

  const Videoplayeritem({
    Key key,
    this.videourl,
    this.currentPageIndex,
    this.isPaused,
    this.pageIndex,
    this.thumbnailUrl,
    this.pickedvideo,
    this.mute,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoplayeritemState createState() => _VideoplayeritemState();
}

class _VideoplayeritemState extends State<Videoplayeritem> {
  VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;
  bool initialized = false;
  bool stopvideo = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    try {
      videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
        
        widget.videourl,
        
        videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(mixWithOthers: true),
       
      )..initialize().then((value) {
          if (this.mounted) setState(() {});
          try {
            videoPlayerController?.play();
            videoPlayerController?.setLooping(true);
            if (widget.mute) {
              videoPlayerController?.setVolume(0);
            } else if (!widget.mute) {
              videoPlayerController?.setVolume(1);
            }
          } catch (e) {
            print('error: $e');
          }
        });
    } catch (e) {
      print('error2: $e');
    }

    print('init');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    try {
      if (videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying) {
        videoPlayerController?.pause();
      }

      videoPlayerController?.setVolume(0);
      videoPlayerController?.dispose();
      videoPlayerController = null;
    } catch (e) {
      print('error3: $e');
    }

    print('dispose');
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.pageIndex == widget.currentPageIndex &&
            !widget.isPaused &&
            !stopvideo ||
        widget.pageIndex == widget.pickedvideo &&
            widget.currentPageIndex == null &&
            !stopvideo) {
      setState(() {
        videoPlayerController?.play();
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        videoPlayerController?.pause();
      });
    }
    if (widget.mute) {
      videoPlayerController?.setVolume(0);
    } else if (!widget.mute) {
      videoPlayerController?.setVolume(1);
    }
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Center(
          child: videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized
              ? GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    if (videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying) {
                      if (this.mounted) {
                        setState(() {
                          stopvideo = true;
                          videoPlayerController?.pause();
                        });
                      }
                    } else {
                      if (this.mounted) {
                        setState(() {
                          stopvideo = false;
                          videoPlayerController?.play();
                          videoPlayerController?.setLooping(true);
                        });
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  child: VisibilityDetector(
                    key: Key("unique keys"),
                    onVisibilityChanged: (VisibilityInfo info) {
                      debugPrint(
                          "${info.visibleFraction} of my widget is visible");
                      if (info.visibleFraction == 0) {
                        print("pause");
                        if (stopvideo == false) {
                          if (this.mounted) {
                            setState(() {
                              stopvideo = true;
                            });
                          }
                        }

                        videoPlayerController?.pause();
                      } else if (widget.pageIndex == widget.currentPageIndex ||
                          widget.pageIndex == widget.pickedvideo &&
                              widget.currentPageIndex == null) {
                        if (this.mounted) {
                          if (stopvideo == true) {
                            setState(() {
                              stopvideo = false;
                            });
                          }
                        }

                        videoPlayerController?.play();
                      } else {}
                    },
                    child: Stack(children: [
                      Center(
                        child: AspectRatio(
                          aspectRatio: videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
                          child: VideoPlayer(videoPlayerController),
                        ),
                      ),
                      PlayPauseOverlay(
                        controller: videoPlayerController,
                        stopvideo: stopvideo,
                      )
                    ]),
                  ))
              : Center(
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                      imageUrl: widget.thumbnailUrl,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
    );
  }
}
```

My app is playing videos in Preloadpageview which are vertical scrollable like reels in instagram. The videos are loaded from stream .

Hope anyone can explain what chaching exactly mean and how it will affect my high bandwidth . Also how to used it in my case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem that I had was a high bandwidth in my flutter /firebase application . I had like 19gb a day with 10-20 videos and like up to 10 users.

There are two layers where caching can with this problem: initial video download, and subsequent video replay.

For initial video download, one option is to dedicate a server to act as an intermediary cache. It would download and stay in sync with the current `videourl`'s content and then serve it. The `videourl`s would then be pointed to this server so the client pulls videos from it. 
This only moves the problem around though, and bandwidth isn't free. But you don't have to host this cache server, there are companies that will host for a fee.

The way caching can help for subsequent video replay is by keeping it in local temporary storage on the video playing client, and when returning to the video, retrieving it from local temporary storage and playing it - thereby avoiding asking it from the server again.

One possibly quick solution could be by using the `better_player` library. It allows many configurations, including using a cache. You can find it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player)

Answer (score 2):

I might be a little late to answer the question, but if you or anybody else out there are still looking for the answer here's how I did it.

After trying every possible library out there I ended up making my own "video cacher". Note: This might not be the prettiest or the slickest solution, but it gets the job done.

On my main file:

> Homepage.dart

```
body: FutureBuilder(
        future: FetchPostData,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return SizedBox(
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
               child: VideoCacher(snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()['VideoUrl'])))
```

I had a future builder using a cached future stream. Now the data I got form that stream I passed it into another file with a stateful widget called: VideoCacher.dart

> VideoCacher.dart

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getMedia();
  }

  Future<void> getMedia() async {
    String exp = r'(_.*\.(mp4))';
    final RegExp regExp = RegExp(exp);
    final String? fileName = regExp.stringMatch(widget._videoUrl);
    final Directory tmpDir = Directory.systemTemp;
    final File file = File('${tmpDir.path}/$fileName');

    if (file.existsSync() == false) {
      FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('videos')
          .child(fileName!)
          .writeToFile(file);
      setState(() {
        _cachedFile = file;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _cachedFile = file;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PostVideoPlayer(_cachedFile);
  }
}
```

In this file I created a tmp location on the system directory where I would download the film from the data I got in stream and pass it on to another file called: VideoPlayer.dart

> VideoPlayer.dart

Here I would use the original video_player library provided by flutter team to output the video to my main file.

```
body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        children: [
          SizedBox.expand(
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: _controller.value.size.width,
                height: _controller.value.size.height,
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

> So the chain would be: Homepage.dart < return VideoCacher.dart <
> return VideoPlayer.dart

Prior to this I had my bandwidth consumption at hitting the daily limit in just couple of minutes. Even though I only had 3 videos and total storage of about 2mb.

What I noticed was that anytime you put anything that even remotely relies on fetching data or dynamic data you are bound to run into problems as build method is called every time there is a change. So if you try to get video from storage it will send thousands of requests in succession until you run out of bandwidth.

After this method my bandwidth consumption was around couple mbs, before the video was downloaded and 0mb after it was cached.

Let me know if you found this helpful.
Good Luck.